# A strange sequence of polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_{7}$

Tags: polynomials, number-theory, finite-field

Let $P=X^{10} +5X^{5}+1$ and $Q=5X^{8}+6X^{3}$ in $\mathbb{F}*{7}[X]$. How we can prove this strange relation of Euclid division
$$U*{2i}P-X^{4}U_{2i-1}^{7}=4.3^{2i-1}Q$$
$$U_{2i+1}P-X^{-4}U_{2i}^{7}=4.3^{2i}Q/X$$
with $U_{1}=X^{2}$?Note that $U_{2i}=[X^{4}U_{2i-1}^{7}/P]$ and $U_{2i+1}=[X^{-4}U_{2i}^{7}/P]$.

Comment: You may want to post this in [math stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) .

Comment: For $i=1$, $4.3^{2i-1}Q=5Q=4X^{8}+2X^{3}$

Comment: For $i=2$, $4.3^{2i-1}Q=3Q=X^{8}+4X^{3}$

Comment: I'm not sure what is meant by `4.3`. Again, it would be better to post this at [math stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finite-fields) .

Comment: I wanted to do it but they answer me: Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this type of finite field. I don't understand how 4.3^(1) == 5 or 4.3^(3) == 3.

Comment: In some cases, 4.3 is an alternate way to express 4^3, but (4^3)%7 == 1 for both integer and binary (xor) math, not 5.